# Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 + JavaFX NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, javafx

I'm Trying to learn Spring framework and integrate it with Hibernate and JavaFX.
I've done base configuration for H2 database. I have face an Error witch i don't know how to solve.

My project file structure is like so:

[image]

Spring configuration files:

beanLocations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>


    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="../beans/engine.xml"/>
</beans
```

engine.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Stock Data Access Object -->
    <bean id="daoEngine" class="dao.daoimpl.EngineDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Stock business object -->
    <bean id="engineBo" class="bo.boimpl.EngineBOImpl">
        <property name="engineDAO" ref="daoEngine"/>
    </bean>




</beans>
```

datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">


        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/hibernate/Engine.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

EngineBoImpl.java

```
public class EngineBOImpl implements EngineBO {


    @Autowired
    EngineDAO engineDAO;

    public EngineBOImpl() {
    }

    public void setEngineDAO(EngineDAO engineDAO) {
        this.engineDAO = engineDAO;
    }

    public void Save(Engine obj) {
        engineDAO.Save(obj);

    }

    public void Update(Engine obj) {
        engineDAO.Update(obj);
    }

    public void Delete(Engine obj) {
        engineDAO.Delete(obj);
    }
}
```

EngineBO.java

```
public interface EngineBO extends BO<Engine> {

}

BO.java

public interface BO<T> {
    void Save(T obj);

    void Update(T obj);

    void Delete(T obj);

}
```

Unit test:

```
public class engineBo {

    @Test
    public void testInsertEngine() {
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        engine.setName("Cobra");
        engine.setSerialNumber(321321321);

        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/beanLocations.xml");


        EngineBOImpl engineBO = (EngineBOImpl) context.getBean("engineBO");
        engineBO.Save(engine);

        Assert.assertTrue(true);


    }
}
```

Here is Stack trace :

```
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFOS: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@66133adc: startup date [Mon Nov 21 21:33:42 WAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/config/beanLocations.xml]
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/database/DataSource.xml]
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/database/Hibernate.xml]
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/beans/engine.xml]
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFOS: Loading properties file from class path resource [properties/database.properties]
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.4.Final}
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:44 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:46 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
nov. 21, 2016 9:33:50 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
AVERTISSEMENT: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [bo.boimpl.EngineBOImpl] for bean with name 'engineBo' defined in class path resource [spring/beans/engine.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bo/EngineBO (wrong name: bo/engineBo)

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [bo.boimpl.EngineBOImpl] for bean with name 'engineBo' defined in class path resource [spring/beans/engine.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bo/EngineBO (wrong name: bo/engineBo)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:734)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at bo.engineBo.testInsertEngine(engineBo.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bo/EngineBO (wrong name: bo/engineBo)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1353)
    ... 36 more
```

So, why this error Occurs, if EngineImpl exists.

Comment: Can you also post `EngineBo.java` (the interface)? Looks like you may have either misnamed it `engineBo` or misnamed the source file `engineBo.java`...

Comment: Edited, adding EngineBO.java , Bo.java , enginBo.java(Test code)

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, when you deploy this, the OS is not going to be able to distinguish between your test class `bo.engineBo` and your business interface `bo.EngineBO`. Use proper naming conventions and use a distinct package name for your test classes.

Comment: Okay, Thank's James_D, Stupid error but finally we find it.